# Issue when Converting HTML to PDF on Server Only , Itextsharp , C#

Tags: c#, itext, html-to-pdf

I am using the following code to generate PDF From HTML.

```
 public byte[] GetPDF(StringBuilder pHTML)
    {
        try
        {
            MyError.LogSystemError("In GET PDF", (new System.IO.FileInfo(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)).Name, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, Session["UserID"].ToString(), Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
            byte[] bPDF = null;

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(pHTML.ToString());

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                MyError.LogSystemError("Before Parse", (new System.IO.FileInfo(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)).Name, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, Session["UserID"].ToString(), Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                MyError.LogSystemError("After Parse", (new System.IO.FileInfo(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)).Name, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, Session["UserID"].ToString(), Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
                pdfDoc.Close();

                bPDF = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            return bPDF;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyError.LogSystemError(ex, (new System.IO.FileInfo(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)).Name, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, Session["UserID"].ToString(), Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here When I run this on Local it works perfectly and on server I got the following error:
"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

I have tried so many solutions to make it work on server but no luck.
I have tried with connection timeout update in IIS as well as config, that won't work.

Comment: Don't use `HTMLWorker`, it is obsolete. Use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: I tried with XMLWorker too. but no luck there

Comment: My comment was not related to the problem you have, that's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer. Nevertheless you should still use XMLWorker.

Comment: I used "HtmlToPdf" instead of itextsharp and it works. I guess there might be rights issue for itextsharp on server. Thanks for help.

Comment: For the benefit of other people with the same question, please share your solution as an answer (including your code). Stack Overflow only works if people give back to the community.

Comment: Sure that's the reason I have not added as answer. I am waiting for the correct answer and also from my side research is on. Hopefully someone have idea of the same

Comment: A question can have more than one answer.